# Access Json outside of javascript each function

Tags: javascript, json

below is my script,

```
var holidays = {};
    var count=0;
    $('.row').each(function(index) {
        var names = document.getElementById('name['+count+']').value;
        var dates = document.getElementById('dateh['+count+']').value;          
        holidays[names] = dates;
        count ++;
        console.log(holidays);
    });
```

If i do `console.log(holidays);` inside the function i can get the json object, but if i do the same outside of `$('.row').each(function(index)` it's not printing any.

Did anyone know where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: Some error in your code beside that in your post. Paste the whole related code, so we can find the problem.

Comment: I'm not sold on square-brackets in *dom* IDs but if your markup is *"correct"* [what you've posted works](http://jsfiddle.net/hmjD5/).  You will need to elaborate further.

Answer (score -1):

declare array like

```
var holidays = [];
```

or

```
var holidays = new Array();
```

Comment: i think OP need key value pair, javascript array can't do that.

Comment: @Dariel `typeof []`... *technically* they can - but this isn't the issue.